# How to switch between difference "frames"

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have been recently learning how to use `tkinter` and I wanted to switch between 2 different `canvas` (whatever term is more appropriate) using buttons. However, whenever I click between the buttons to switch frames the screen doesn't seem to clear. Any way to fix this?

```
#Imports
import tkinter as tk

#master means the variable

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.title("Testing") #Setting the title
        self.master.minsize(800, 600) #The minimum size it can be
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="black")

        self.section1()

    def section2(self):

        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        #Creating the canvas and drawing a line

        self.canvas.create_line(15, 25, 200, 25, fill="red")

        #Going back to the "main menu"
        self.exit = tk.Button(self, text="exit", fg="red", command=self.section1)
        self.exit.place(x=0, y=50)

        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def section1(self): #Main menu
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="See Line", fg="red", command=self.section2)
        self.button.place(x=0, y=0)

        #Exit button
        self.exit = tk.Button(self, text="exit", fg="red", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.exit.place(x=0, y=25)


window = App() #Declaring the window
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I only see one Canvas in your code. What do you want to switch to?

Comment: `section1()` and `section2()` are not *"frames"*.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between widgets (here `canvas`, but it could be `frames`, or `buttons`, or `labels`, etc.) using the geometry manager `pack`-`pack_forget` (or `grid`-`grid_forget`)

Maybe like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Testing")
        self.minsize(800, 600)
        self.swap_btn = tk.Button(self, text='swap canvas', command=self.swap_canvas)
        self.swap_btn.pack()
        
        self.canvas1 = tk.Canvas(self, bg="black")
        self.canvas2 = tk.Canvas(self, bg="blue")
        
        self.canvasses = [self.canvas2, self.canvas1]
        self.current_canvas = self.canvas1
        self.current_canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.draw_some_stuff()
        
    def swap_canvas(self):
        self.current_canvas.pack_forget()
        self.current_canvas = self.canvasses.pop(0)
        self.canvasses.append(self.current_canvas)
        self.current_canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        
    def draw_some_stuff(self):
        self.canvas1.create_oval(200, 200, 300, 300, fill='blue')
        self.canvas2.create_rectangle(200, 200, 300, 300, fill='black')
        self.canvas1.create_oval(400, 200, 500, 300, fill='blue')
        self.canvas2.create_rectangle(400, 200, 500, 300, fill='black')
        

window = App() #Declaring the window
window.mainloop()
```